# remove index.php only from frontend not in backend in magento

Tags: magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I want to remove index.php only from frontend, not in backend in Magento. please someone help me in this issue.

we try to resolve this issue using .htaccess by following section.

```
        <pre>
         RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
         RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
         RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php(/[^\s\?]+)? [NC]
         RewriteRule ^ %1/ [L,R=301]    
        </pre>
```

but after use this code, it add the extra back slashes in the admin url that create issue in manage categories section. I am not able to expand all categories.

if i use the below solution then it remove the index.php from admin url also.

Answer (score 0):

Set `system -> configuration -> general -> web -> search engines optimization` 'use web server rewrites' to yes and flush cache.

You need mod_rewrite to be enabled on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to remove index.php from URLs in Magento

```
Step 1:
* Goto to your site root folder and you can find the htaccess file there.Open it on text editor and find the line #Rewrite Base/magento.
* Just replace it with Rewrite Base/

Step 2:
* Then goto your admin panel and enable the Rewrites(set yes for Use Web Server Rewrites).
* You can find it at System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization.

Step 3:
* Then goto Cache management page (system cache management ) and refresh your cache and refresh to check the site.
```